# How can i tell if a photo was taken from the phone or downloaded from somewhere else?

Tags: samsung

How can i tell if a photo from the samsung galaxy 7 was taken from the phone or it was downloaded from another app or site or sent to the phone

Comment: Check its EXIF info.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Gallery/Google Photos app, long press the photo and check the details. It should contain the required information.

Comment: Can you make this answer more detailed?